# Better way to validate when not using a function ValidateSet

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a better way to validate a "response" from a user for my script. I know you can use a function to validate this but I want it to be more interactive.

```
$DPString = @"
Enter users department.
Valid choices are;
"Accounts","Claims","Broker Services","Underwriting","Compliance","HR","IT","Developmet","Legal" and "Legal Underwriting"
"@
$Department = Read-Host "$DPString"
do
{
    Switch ($Department)
{
    Accounts { $DepBool = $true }
    Claims { $DepBool = $true }
    "Broker Services" { $DepBool = $true }
    Underwriting { $DepBool = $true }
    Compliance { $DepBool = $true }
    "Legal Underwriting" { $DepBool = $true }
    Legal { $DepBool = $true }
    HR { $DepBool = $true }
    IT { $DepBool = $true }
    Development { $DepBool = $true }
    Default { $DepBool = $false }
    }
    if ($DepBool -eq $true)
    {
        $DepLoop = $false
    }
    else {
        $Department = Read-Host "Please enter a valid Department"
        $DepLoop = $true
    }
}    
while ($DepLoop)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear in what context the user is being prompted for input, but I would favour a list of valid parameters being passed in on the command line.  I would make them mutually exclusive using [Parameter Sets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/12/23/powershell-v2-parametersets.aspx).

However, if this is a part of a larger script which prompts for input part way through, then it might be appropriate to prompt for input using the windows API for displaying an input box.  Here's a link which describes this approach in more detail [Creating a Custom Input Box](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx).

Although it feels wrong to display UI from powershell, I understand that there are times when this is desirable, using the link above here's an implementation of a ListBox, you simply pass it a string array and it returns the selected value:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS 
    Displays a Windows List Control and returns the selected item
.EXAMPLE
    Get-ListBoxChoice -Title "Select Environment" -Prompt "Choose an environment" -Options @("Option 1","Option 2")
    This command displays a list box containing two options.
.NOTES
    There are two command buttons OK and Cancel, selecting OK will return the selected option, whilst
    Cancel will return nothing.
.RELATED LINKS
    http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx
#>
Function Get-ListBoxChoice
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
        [string] $Title,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
        [string] $Prompt,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
        [string[]] $Options
    )

    Write-Verbose "Get-ListBoxChoice"
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

    $uiForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
    $uiForm.Text = $Title
    $uiForm.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
    $uiForm.MaximizeBox = $false
    $uiForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,240) 
    $uiForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

    $uiForm.KeyPreview = $True
    $uiForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
        {$chosenValue=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$uiForm.Close()}})
    $uiForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
        {$uiForm.Close()}})

    $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,160)
    $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $OKButton.Text = "OK"
    $OKButton.Add_Click({$chosenValue=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$uiForm.Close()})
    $uiForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

    $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,160)
    $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
    $CancelButton.Add_Click({$uiForm.Close()})
    $uiForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

    $uiLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $uiLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
    $uiLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
    $uiLabel.Text = $Prompt
    $uiForm.Controls.Add($uiLabel) 

    $objListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
    $objListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
    $objListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
    $objListBox.Height = 120

    $Options | % {
        [void] $objListBox.Items.Add($_)
    }

    $uiForm.Controls.Add($objListBox) 
    $uiForm.Topmost = $True

    $uiForm.Add_Shown({$uiForm.Activate()})
    [void] $uiForm.ShowDialog()

    $chosenValue
}
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply, I'm using this to capture information in a larger script and prefer to keep it in the cli. With parameter sets it dose provide a nicer way to validate but breaks out of the command when its not valid, I need something that'll give instant feed back and give the user opportunity to correct their mistake, dose that make sense?

Comment: In which case I would use the second approach, which gives them the dropdown, which has leaves no opportunity for mistakes.

Comment: While that option is very nice, do you think there is a better way to do it only in CLI and have no inputbox?

Comment: I'm not sure I can think of another way, let's see what the rest of the community comes up with, come back and update with an answer if you do find a way as I would be interested in seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

If they're running at least V3, you can use Out-Gridview:

```
$Departments = @(
[PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'Accounts';Description = 'Accounting Department'}
[PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'Claims';Description = 'Claims Department'}
[PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'Broker';Description = 'Broker Services'}
)


$GridParams = @{
 Title = "Select a department, and press 'OK', or 'Cancel' to quit."
 OutPutMode = 'Single'
 }

$Department = $Departments | Out-Gridview @GridParams

If ($Department)
 { #Do stuff }
```